# how to retrieve node names and node properties in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

please am new to firebase and am trying to get the node names as shown below
[My database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27GtF.png)

i have a node courses under a user node and different courses codes node under the course node. what i want to achieve is to get all the course codes and their course name and store it in an array list for example an array list to store course codes and another to store course name
the Below code is what i have done

```
 final ArrayList<String> test=new ArrayList<String>();
myFirebaseRef.child(uid).child("Course").child("CEESE001").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                courses ok=snapshot.getValue(courses.class);
            test.add(ok.getCourseName());

            }
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, test);

            // Here, set the data in  ListView
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

the above code is what i hv tried but i need to dynamically get the course code rather than putting a static course code pls how do i achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to get all the courses names and codes?

Comment: yes this is what I want

Comment: I posted an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
    List<String> coursesNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> coursesCodes=new ArrayList<String>();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("Course");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                coursesCodes.add(snap.getKey());
                coursesNames.add(snap.child("Course Details").child("courseName").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, please consider mark the answer as correct if it helped